# Oracle Pivot Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am fairly new to Pivoting and trying to Pivot based on two columns.

Data I have:

[image]

Data I want to Achieve after pivoting:

[image]

My Query which is Flawed:

```
   select *
from
(
  select ISSUEID,ANSWER, ANSWERCOMMENT,QUESTION ,QUESTIONID
  from issue_survey
  WHERE ISSUEID = 6877
) d
pivot
(
  max(QUESTION)
  for QUESTIONID  in (1 QUESTION1,2 QUESTION2, 3 QUESTION3)
) piv;
```

The Results I am getting with this flawed query:

[image]

Any suggestions with this are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select *
from
(
  select ISSUEID,ANSWER, ANSWERCOMMENT,QUESTION ,
         rownum rn
  from issue_survey
  WHERE ISSUEID = 6877
) d
pivot
(
  max(QUESTION) as question, max(Answer) as answer,
  max( ANSWERCOMMENT ) as ANSWERCOMMENT
  for rn  in ( 1 ,2 , 3 )
) piv;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5aba7/6

```
| ISSUEID |        1_QUESTION | 1_ANSWER | 1_ANSWERCOMMENT |   2_QUESTION | 2_ANSWER | 2_ANSWERCOMMENT |      3_QUESTION | 3_ANSWER | 3_ANSWERCOMMENT |
|---------|-------------------|----------|-----------------|--------------|----------|-----------------|-----------------|----------|-----------------|
|    6877 | Do you wanna wait |      YES |           TEST1 | How about it | Its okay |           TEST2 | Sample question |   (null) |           TEST3
```